# How to make my "own" templated map?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, interface-implementation

I want to implement my own "simple" container which will have map properties but also keeps insertion order. I've heard about boost::multi_index but I find it very difficult to understand for what I want.

So I made a templated class:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class MyMap {
    private : 
        std::vector<KEY>    m_keys;
        std::vector<VALUE>  m_values;

    public :
        void insert(KEY& key, VALUE& val) {
            //Test if key exists //
            m_keys.push_back(key);
            m_values.push_back(val);
        }

        /* Other methods like erase/size/operator[]/begin/etc. */

};
```

Just to test it, I wanted to do something like this:

```
int main() {
    MyMap<string,int> m;
    m.insert("test",1);
    m.insert("cat",2);

    for(auto& item : m) {
        cout << item << endl;
        cout << m[item] << endl;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a compilation error on inserts (and [ ]) as it translates my KEY into a basic_string and not a string. It's driving me crazy and I can't find any answer (or any word to properly describe my problem to research for an answer). I guess it has something to do with allocators but I can't manage to understand how to fix it.
How can I make my map do this conversion but also stays general as I will need it with other (own-implemented) classes?

**EDIT :** After solving "string" problem, I had problems when passing int because it was waiting for an &int. Followed kebs advice and implemented a vector> instead and got rid of conversion problems... :)

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the container provided by standard library ?

Comment: @kebs : Yes, I want to keep the order of insertion because I'll need it later, but I also have to associate some class with an unique key :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way to go. You could also store in a `std::vector` some `std::pair<Index,Type>` (unless you need to access through the key). But from a general point of view, I think situations where the standard library doesn't fit are very rare...

Comment: It's merely a wrapping that I wanted to do :)
I also had think of a vector<pair<>> but I've found (on the Net) that maybe two vectors may be better as we only have one vector to go through to find the right index?

Comment: IMHO, parsing one vector holding a key, or parsing a vector holding a pair holding a key will absolutely make no runtime difference. But you are free to try and compare...

Comment: @kebs actually, there are some rare cases where std::map and std::unordered_map are not cool. this is where performance does matter. flat maps like the OP try can win std::(unordered_)map by few magnitutes.

Comment: Just for the record, I benchmarked array operator [] lookup times for this method and using 2 vectors this way is significantly slower (at least 750 times slower with 1,000,000 random elements) than using 1 vector and 1 unordered map (or even 1 vector and 2 unordered maps).

Comment: I just realized that I got my benchmark numbers mixed up. It's actually for sequential elements that using two vectors is at least 750 times slower than using 1 vector and 1 map (which is where my initial figure came from) whereas it's ~5000 times slower than using than using 1 vector and 1 unordered map. However, for random elements, it's 30 times and ~140 times slower, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build a reference from a `const char*` (even though it gets casted to a string), try this instead:

```
    template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
    void insert(KEY key, VALUE val) {
        m_keys.push_back(key);
        m_values.push_back(val);
    }
```

More precisely, the compiler is pretty clear about the problem:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::basic_string&' from an rvalue of type 'std::basic_string'
>       m.insert("test",1);

Comment: But there, I will pass args by values and not reference right? This class is also intended to store whole classes so I was trying to avoid that!

Comment: Anyhow, `vector::push_back()` will do a copy. And the initial value passed, although it appears to create a copy, it will be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: I didn't have the compiler error you edited in :)
I did forget that push_back() made a copy, thank you :)